# How to stop ComboBox from opening on Ctrl-Enter?

Tags: c#, winforms

Winforms C#. Trying to make Ctrl-Enter on a ComboBox do program-specific stuff and not anything else.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
        cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
        cb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20,50);
        cb.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(CBKeyDown);
        cb.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(CBPreviewKeyDown);
        cb.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CBKeyPress);
        this.Controls.Add(cb);

        List<string> someThings = new List<string>();
        someThings.Add("An item");
        someThings.Add("Another item");

        cb.DataSource = someThings; 
    }

    private void CBPreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                if (e.Control)
                { 
                    e.IsInputKey = true;
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void CBKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Enter:
                if (e.Control)
                {
                    //Do application specific stuff
                    e.Handled = true;
                }

                break;
        }
    }

    private void CBKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\n')
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When the ComboBox has focus and I hit Ctrl-Enter the ComboBox dropdown pops up in response to the key even though I have set `e.handled = true`. I have confirmed that the issue is related to the ComboBox AutoCompleteMode Suggest functionality. If this line is commented out or changed to Append, it stops doing it. But I like the autocomplete functionality and want to keep it if I can.

I have stepped through with the debugger and verified that the dropdown is popping up after the code passes through e.handled=true in the KeyDown event but before the KeyPress event ever fires.

How can I make the ComboBox not respond to Ctrl-Enter except as I explicitly direct?

Comment: Try to reproduce the problem by creating a [MCVE]. This way, you can find the problem yourself or if you couldn't find, community users can use your code to reproduce the problem and try to help you.

Comment: Should I delete this and create a new question, or modify this one?

Comment: Since no one has posted an answer, it's better to change this question and include [MCVE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this in a derived `ComboBox` by overriding the [ProcessCmdKey Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.processcmdkey?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Add this class definition to your project and perform a built operartion.  The control will show up in the toolbox (assuming VS is configured to add user defined controls) near the top under "Your project Name" Components section.  This class exposes the event ControlEnterPressed to facilitate taking a desired action on the key stokes.

```
public class CB : ComboBox
{
    public event Action<CB> ControlEnterPressed;

    protected virtual void OnControlEnterPressed()
    {
        ControlEnterPressed?.Invoke(this);
    }

    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(keyData.ToString());
        // runs before ProcessDialogKey, ProcessDialogKey is called if this method returns false
        bool ret = false;
        if ((keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Control) || keyData.HasFlag(Keys.ControlKey)) && (keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Return) || keyData.HasFlag(Keys.Enter)))
        {
            BeginInvoke(new Action(OnControlEnterPressed)); //let message processing finish before raising the event
            ret = true;   // indicate key handled
        }
        else
        {
            ret = base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: This seems like it is in the right ballpark but ProcessCmdKey does not pick up Ctrl-Enter.  I modified it and did some testing with breakpoints and this is what I found:

Testing for Keys.Control picks up [Ctrl] but it is hard to test combinations because the debugger stops before the 2nd key is pressed.

Keys.Return and Keys.Enter are both true for either [Enter] key, main or numberpad.

[Ctrl]-[Enter] does not activate Keys.Return or Keys.Enter or the condition you wrote.  I don't think ProcessCmdKey is getting called on the control for it.

Comment: @LanceWisely, I tested it and it works.  However, it may be a keyboard issue where my system sends a `Keys.Return` and possibly yours is sending a `Keys.Enter`.  I will update the code to check for either Return or Enter.   I will also add a Debug.Print statement that you can observer in the immediate window for the detected key combination.  Please let me know what you see from the `Debug.Print` output.

Comment: This what I got from the following key sequence:  [Enter], [Ctrl], [Ctrl-Enter], [Ctrl-X] -------

Return ----

ControlKey, Control ----

ControlKey, Control ----

ControlKey, Control ----

X, Control  (I added dashes for readability)

Comment: This is VS 2017, Windows 10 64-bit, .NET 4.7.02556  Laptop keyboard.

Comment: Interesting, so [Ctrl-Enter] yields "Return ---- ControlKey".  OK, I just updated the conditional code to check for Keys.ControlKey.  Please try that.  Thanks for the feed-back.  Hopefully, I convered all possible permutations this time.

Comment: It doesn't.  Enter yields Return.  Ctrl-X will yield ControlKey, Control and then X, Control.  (one when I hit ctrl and the other when I hit both).  Ctrl-Enter gives the first ControlKey, Control when I hit the Ctrl key but nothing when I hit both.

Comment: Do you still have the `CBPreviewKeyDown` event wired on the new control?  If so, remove it and the other KeyDown and Keypressed handlers as well.

Comment: That was it.  Taking out the IsInputKey for Ctrl-Enter from the PreviewKeyDown handler made it work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach would be to set drop down's height to 1.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
    cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    cb.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
    cb.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
    cb.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(20, 50);
    cb.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(CBKeyDown);
    cb.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.PreviewKeyDownEventHandler(CBPreviewKeyDown);
    cb.KeyPress += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventHandler(CBKeyPress);
    this.Controls.Add(cb);

    List<string> someThings = new List<string>();
    someThings.Add("An item");
    someThings.Add("Another item");

    cb.DataSource = someThings;
}

private void CBPreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
            if (e.Control)
            {
                e.IsInputKey = true;
            }

            break;
    }

    // Return back drop down height, in case ctrl + enter keys were pressed
    (sender as ComboBox).DropDownHeight = 100;
}

private void CBKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Enter:
            if (e.Control)
            {
                // Do application specific stuff
                e.Handled = true;

                // Set drop down height to 1, in order to set height
                // that looks like drop down is not showed at all (only 1 pixel)
                (sender as ComboBox).DropDownHeight = 1;
            }

            break;
    }
}


private void CBKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == '\n')
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does workaround the issue.  There's still a visual change on the CB but it's minor.  I'm a little concerned that the official documentation says [not to put any logic in PreviewKeyDown other than setting IsInputKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.previewkeydown?view=netframework-4.7.2).  It doesn't say why you shouldn't do this so I don't know what I'm messing with.

I'm still hoping someone can explain how to properly intercept the keystroke.